# Magento custom admin tab not working in live server

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I am added a custom module in magento which adding two new tabs in sales order section it is working fine in local but when i tried it in live server it is not working. throws some error like "Wrong tab configuration.". While checking i think it is issue with the layout file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout>
<adminhtml_sales_order_view>
    <reference name="sales_order_tabs">
        <action method="addTab">
            <name>name_custom</name>
            <block>mymodule/adminhtml_sales_order_view_tab_mymodule</block>
        </action>
        <action method="addTab">
            <name>name_custom2</name>
            <block>mymodule/adminhtml_sales_order_view_tab_mymodule1</block>
        </action>
    </reference>
</adminhtml_sales_order_view>
```

and in my config.xml block is defined like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
..............
..............
    <blocks>
        <mymodule>
            <class>Company_Mymodule_Block</class>
        </mymodule>
    </blocks>
...............
...............
```

I am confused where the problem is when i tried **adminhtml/sales_order_view_tab_invoices** instead of **mymodule/adminhtml_sales_order_view_tab_mymodule** in layout it is working. how can i solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working in local and not working in live server?
Most likely it is caused by case sensitive naming (linux is case sensitive).
Double check your module name, etc.

eg:

`adminhtml/sales_order_view_tab_invoices` -> ok

`adminhtml/sales_oRder_view_tab_invoices` -> error

Comment: Yes. there are some problems with my folder names. That cause the problems. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your :

`mymodule/adminhtml_sales_order_view_tab_mymodule` and `mymodule/adminhtml_sales_order_view_tab_mymodule1`

is an instance of Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tab_Interface.

You can use `implements Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tab_Interface`